# Merging 3 Regular Expressions to make a Slug/URL validation check

Tags: c#, regex, url, annotations, slug

I am trying to merge a few working RegEx patterns together (AND them). I don't think I am doing this properly, further, the first RegEx might be getting in the way of the next two.

Slug example (no special characters except for `-` and `_`):

```
(^[a-z0-9-_]+$)
```

Then I would like to ensure the first character is NOT `-` or `_`:

```
(^[^-_])
```

Then I would like to ensure the last character is NOT `-` or `_`:

```
([^-_]$)
```

Match (good Alias):

- my-new_page
- pagename

Not-Match (bad Alias)

- -my-new-page
- my-new-page_
- !@#$%^&*()

If this RegExp can be simplified and I am more than happy to use it.  I am trying to create validation on a page URL that the user can provide, I am looking for the user to:

- Not start or and with a special character
- Start and end with a number or letter
- middle (not start and end) can include `-` and `_`

One I get that working, I can tweak if for other characters as needed.

In the end I am applying as an `Annotation` to my model like so:

```
[RegularExpression(
    @"(^[a-z0-9-_]+$)?(^[^-_])?([^-_]$)", 
    ErrorMessage = "Alias is not valid")
]
```

Thank you, and let me know if I should provide more information.

Comment: `^[a-z\d](?:[a-z\d_-]*[a-z\d])?$`

Comment: If you want a simple environment in which to test your RegEx, [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) is pretty neat, there are many other tools of such. Unfortunately, I'm pretty bad at making regex by hand and usually avoid them seeing how heavy they are.

Comment: @Antry http://regexstorm.net/tester for .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Y35cVe/1)

```
^[a-z\d](?:[a-z\d_-]*[a-z\d])?$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[a-z\d]` Match any lowercase ASCII letter or digit
- `(?:[a-z\d_-]*[a-z\d])?` Optionally match the following

  - `[a-z\d_-]*` Match any character in the set any number of times
  - `[a-z\d]` Match any lowercase ASCII letter or digit
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##TVBdT4MwFH1uf8W1TtMuwg@QmC0xezBxL2riw2Sksg6bQCG9RZmE344dsEiT2/txzr2nvSkGaWlV39eoTQavJ3SqiOg8C99U48IXldW5tJumsgpRlwYjSqv6M9cppLlEhE0jiypXtKVkqqOTzrvvUh9gK7XhghKPEj9LNWCH@wGM@oGhwtdsv5PB78ch5qv7MUqCeDnVxGrBROTb0Vn/ul0MY4B@RsuKU@AHJZXMFLsDdvZGFkMcjFhwwWZpcs6v1teLm/3tkgvWRRSmQ7zS0a9Gpl98FAIEbS6iAtp/KtFH4MN/wifcSnduEWKGz7nk0S@vzFX4brVTz9ooT57pko4O1tGO9v0f)

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-z\d](?:[a-z\d_-]*[a-z\d])?$");
        string[] strings = {"my-new_page", "pagename", "-my-new-page", "my-new-page_", "!@#$%^&*()"};

        foreach(string s in strings) {
                if (regex.IsMatch(s))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Result (only positive matches):

```
my-new_page
pagename
```

Comment: Thank you, I see I was approaching it incorrectly as I was trying to take different RegEx and merge together.  I will need to look into each section, for example, I don't quite get the `Non-capturing group` just yet.

Comment: @Derek the non-capture group is just used to group parts of a pattern together. It's identical to a capture group except that whatever it matches doesn't get *captured* in the output.